# a = 'b' make it so string 'a' can be changed to the variable a to equal the string 'b'

Tags: python, python-3.x

So in python I want to change a character string into a literal:

```
a = 'b'
b = 'c'
c = 'd'

encoded = input('Type encoded text and enter for decoded text: ')
decoded_list = MAKE_LITERAL_AND_SHOW_VALUES(list(encoded))
    ##Example: ['a','b','c'] becomes [a, b, c] so becomes ['b','c','d']
decoded = CONCATENATE(decoded_list)
    ##Example: ['b','c','a'] becomes 'bcd'
print(decoded)
```

Are there any functions to make this possible?

Comment: It's not very clear at all what you're trying to do. Please describe the actual problem you're trying to solve. As far as the concatenation goes, that's easy. `"".join(['b','c','a'])` gives you `'bca'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use a dictionary instead? I mean, the answer to your direct question is using something like `globals()`... (but I don't recommend it)

```
a = 'b'
b = 'c'
c = 'd'

def MAKE_LITERAL_AND_SHOW_VALUE(encoded):
    return [globals()[i] for i in encoded]

print MAKE_LITERAL_AND_SHOW_VALUE(encoded)
```

The alternative would be:

```
letterDict = {'a':'b', 'b':'c', 'c':'d'}
```

Then, if you wish to use it:

```
def MAKE_LITERAL_AND_SHOW_VALUE(encoded):
    letterDict = {'a':'b', 'b':'c', 'c':'d'}
    return [letterDict[i] for i in encoded]
```

#### Disclaimer:

*(On MattDMo's suggestion)*

Using `globals()` is a bad idea *99.9%* of the time. That's obviously a figure I've made up, but the point is it's almost always unnecessary. I'll venture to guess you like this approach for the same reasons most beginners do; it looks intuitive to use, you might write less code in certain situations, etc.

The problem is you're likely to develop a bad habit. It's not a good design choice to rely upon the global dictionary of your module. This increases coupling, reduces encapsulation and makes code very hard to debug in general. It's not very much unlike passing your variables around with `global` inside of functions. As your program's complexity increases, don't expect others or yourself (in the future) to be any happy with reading the code you write.

Comment: Please don't even MENTION the possibility of using `globals()`. It's a bad, bad thing for newbs (and even some pros I know....) to be messing around with...

Comment: @MattDMo You're right. But what's the point of _not mentioning it_? It's there, it exists. I've put the disclaimer and given my own personal opinion on it. I believe it's important for newbies to understand it one way or another, and I've made my position clear for the OP to understand.

Comment: Yes, you did. I would have emphasized it a little more, if you couldn't tell :)